# Working on Windows Server 2003, errors on 2008 ASP 0104 : 80004005 Operation not Allowed. NOT uploading file. Simple post

Tags: asp-classic

Hey guys we are experiencing a weird issue.
Classic ASP code is working on Windows 2003 Server. 
But on Windows 2008 server when we try to do a simple Request.Form it gives ASP 0104 : 80004005 Operation not Allowed.
Not uploading any file in this request.
Tried send only one value still get the same error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your question seems to be better suited for http://serverfault.com/ , doesn't seem to be programming related (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will ask it there as well. 
Since other programmers can face this issue too, please leave it there as well. 
If it gets answered quicker at serverfault, I'll post the answer here as well.

Comment: http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa115.htm

Comment: pee2pee thanks for your time. 

We tried that but the error is still there. 

And there is no upload involved for this particular step and we tried sending only one value in the request. That didn't resolve it either.

Answer (score 0):

pee2pee's suggestion was very close to the fix. Here are the steps we needed to do.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on the website that has the issue.
3. In IIS Section click on ASP.
4. In Behavior section expand Limits Properties
5. Change "Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit" from 200000 to 500000
6. click Apply on top right corner
7. Didn't need an IIS reset